# VTOL Drone design resources

Tags: long-range-drone, design, ardupilot, pid-tuning, thrust-angle

I would like to make a high performance VTOL drone, and could use some readings and resources. I will also do my own research and try to post what I find here, so that others can reference this. After this research, I would greatly appreciate any feedback on an initial rough design and component selection.

Here are some of the design goals:

- 5-10km max range with custom controller, while maintaining video feed from onboard camera (at least 720p30, ideally better)
- high thrust to weight ratio, to allow flight in up to 20mph winds, and decent maneuverability
- ability to hover in place
- overall accurate control with no drift and good control loops/PID tuning
- efficient design to allow for 30-60 min battery life
- up to 5kg payload capabilities
- reasonably modular to allow for maintenance, upgrades, and addition sensors/actuators

I already have a lot of parts on hand from an octocopter I made that crashed. I could edit this or reply in a comment to list them. However, I would be able to get more parts where necessary.

So obviously making a VTOL drone with these capabilities is extremely difficult. Instead of just randomly drawing up designs, or even just looking at other successful designs out there, I would like some resources on some of the design principles involved here. Specifically,

1. a detailed comparison and evaluation of different VTOL drone designs
2. general UAV and VTOL design guidelines/principles
3. control surfaces in VTOL drones
4. thrust vectoring/differential thrust in VTOL drones
5. control/feedback systems in UAVs and VTOLs drones
6. comparison of commercially available camera and gimbal systems for UAVs (I am unsure what I should get or make here)
7. viable long range, bidirectional radio communication systems (including for video streaming)
8. configuration and programing for VTOL drones with ardupilot
9. counter-rotating propeller performance

Thank you for any help you can provide,

Simon

Comment: This doesn't really suit this forum, as you're asking multiple questions and there's no definitive answer to any of them, so there's no way to rank the answers.